# How to determine which class a Control belongs to in an EventHandler?

Tags: .net, properties, event-handling

This is my class, where I have various properties and also the Panel control:

```
public class Square
{
    private Panel _pSquare;
    public Panel PSquare
    {
        get { return _pSquare; }
        set { _pSquare = value; }
    }
    ....
```

This is the Form Load EventHandler, where a bunch of Square Objects are created:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var n = 0; n < gridSize; n++)
    {
        for (var m = 0; m < gridSize; m++)
        {
            Square squareboard = new Square(n, m);

            squareboard.PSquare.Click += squareEvent;
             ...
```

When the user clicks on a Panel, the pSquare_Click EventHandler is called, so that part works.

```
private void pSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

The problem I have is: how to access the properties of class Square in this EventHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Square class could look like this:

```
public class Square
{
    private readonly Panel _pSquare;

    public Square(Panel pSquare)
    {
        this._pSquare = pSquare;
        this._pSquare.Click += this._pSquare_Click;
    }

    void _pSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.onSquareClicked();
    }

    public event EventHandler SquareClicked;

    private void onSquareClicked()
    {
        EventHandler eventHandler = this.SquareClicked;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

In your form you could make the panels first, and then generate a collection of squares by looping through the panels:

```
    foreach (Panel panel in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        var square = new Square(panel);
        square.SquareClicked += this.squareClicked;
    }
```

Comment: Your example really helped. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Whenever create a panel, Use the `panel.Tag` to links each panel with its square:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var n = 0; n < gridSize; n++)
    {
        for (var m = 0; m < gridSize; m++)
        {
            Square squareboard = new Square(n, m);

            squaredboard.PSquare.Tag = squareboard;
            squareboard.PSquare.Click += squareEvent;
            ...

private void pSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
    Square square = (Square)panel.Tag;//access to the underlying square object
}
```